# Angular update formControl value after selecting mat-option

Tags: angular

I have a Reactive form like below:

```js
this.personForm = this.fb.group({
    firstname: [null, Validators.required],
    lastname: [null, Validators.required],
    home_id: [null],
    home_name: [null, Validators.required],
})
```

I am retrieving the home list from DB using API and fill the mat-option accordingly, so far is okay, by the way I am displaying home_name value only, inside mat-select:

```html
<mat-form-field class="full-width">
    <mat-select placeholder="Select Home" formControlName="home_name">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let home of homes" [value]="home.name">
            {{ home.name }}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>   
</mat-form-field>
```

now I want to post form values after submit, but I dont know how to update home_id when user clicks on home from dropdown menu ?

I tried:

```html
    <mat-select placeholder="Select Home" 
formControlName="home_name" 
(selectionChange)="setHomeId($event.value)">
```

but it is giving me home_name only,

I tried to put the same code inside `<mat-option>` in order to get home object:

```html
<mat-option *ngFor="let home of homes" 
[value]="home_name" 
(selectionChange)="setHomeId($event.value)">
```

but it seems `<mat-option>` does not have function : `(selectionChange)`

Comment: have you implemented ``(ngSubmit)`` ?

Comment: yes, of course I have implemented already

Comment: try [ngValue]="home"

Comment: Can't bind to 'ngValue' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-option'.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you want to do:

```html
<mat-select placeholder="Select Home" formControlName="home_id">
    <!---value is home.id, show home.name--->
    <mat-option *ngFor="let home of homes" [value]="home.id">{{home.name}}
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

It's very crazy you need `home_name` in your `personForm`. I suppose your database only stores `home_id`, if so your `formGroup` must be:

```js
this.personFrom = this.fb.group({
    firstname: [null, Validators.required],
    lastname: [null, Validators.required],
    home_id: [null]
})
```

NOTE: I don't know if is a type error, but looks like is `personForm`, not `personFrom`.

NOTE: **Update** adding `<mat-select formControlName="home_id"..>` as @David said.

Comment: no in the actual code is fine, maybe when I was typing in stackoverflow, I did this typo

Comment: In this example, use `formControlName="home_id"` on the `mat-select` element.

Comment: @DavidWalschots, sorry, I'll try to add it

Answer (score 0):

`<mat-select (selectionChange)="updateHomeId()" </mat-select>`selectionChange Event emitted when the selected value has been changed by the user.

https://material.angular.io/components/select/api

To update reactive form control you can use

```
updateHomeId() {
 this.personFrom.controls['home_id'].setValue("ID");
}
```

https://toddmotto.com/angular-2-form-controls-patch-value-set-value

Hope This Helps.

Comment: I have problem with home_id, the home_name is already received when user clicks or select from dropdown